# std::bind not working as expected

Tags: c++, c++11

```
std::vector<int> v1;
std::function<void(const int&)> funct = 
static_cast<std::function<void(const int&)>>(std::bind(
                                            &std::vector<int>::push_back,
                                            &v1,
                                            std::placeholders::_1));
```

This gives me `no matching function for call to bind`.

I am able to do this though:

```
threadPool.push_back(std::thread(runThread<lazyFunct>,
                     std::bind(&LazySkipList<int>::add,
                     &lsl, std::placeholders::_1), 0, 1000000, 1000000));
```

I am using Xcode 4.4 with llvm C++11 support.

Comment: You're probably better off replacing `std::function<void(const int&)> funct = 
static_cast<std::function<void(const int&)>>(std::bind(...))` with `auto funct = std::bind(...)`. Much more readable imo.

Comment: auto funct =  std::bind(&std::vector<int>::push_back, &v1, std::placeholders::_1); give me the same error ... i accept readability aspect ...

Comment: Yes, all `auto` does in C++11 is infer the type based on what you initialize it with. `auto var = 5;` will produce `var` as an `int`. There are specific cases such as `std::bind` and iterator declarations where this functionality is really useful in my books.

Comment: Get rid of the `static_cast`. You don't need it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is `std::vector::push_back()` is overloaded with the two possible type signatures:

```
void push_back(const T& value);
void push_back(T&& value);
```

As such, the template parameter to `std::bind()` cannot be inferred. However, you can declare the template parameter explicitly:

```
std::bind<void(std::vector<int>::*)(const int&)>(&std::vector<int>::push_back, &v1, std::placeholders::_1);
```

This resolves correctly.

Of course, at this point it might be simpler just to use a lambda:

```
auto func = [&](int i){ v1.push_back(i); };
```

Comment: +1 for the lambda suggestion, which is far nicer in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
auto funct = std::bind(static_cast<void(std::vector<int>::*)(const int&)>
                                             (&std::vector<int>::push_back),
                                              &v1,
                                              std::placeholders::_1);
```

`push_back` is overloaded, so you need to cast it to the proper overload.

Or:

```
void(std::vector<int>::*p)(const int&) = &std::vector<int>::push_back;
auto funct = std::bind(p, &v1, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Or explicitly provide the template argument as shown in Keith Ballard's answer which might be the best actually.

Comment: thanks ... worked as expected by u ...                     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333122/boostbind-stdsetcount-compile-error just to be more clear the above link does not mentions need to cast ...   i expected that not to work so added the cast to bind but not to the function it self ... could not find but have see the trick working ... thanks again ...

Comment: @VishalKumar: Yes, the answer in your linked question is wrong.